# How many swords made of Valyrian Steel are there at the end of Season 6?

Tags: game-of-thrones, weapon

There are many swords made of Valyrian steel. Can anybody throw light on how many are there in total in the known world?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, in the TV show, there are four Valyrian steel swords still known (to the viewer, as opposed to the characters in-universe) to exist:

- Longclaw (Jon Snow)
- Oathkeeper (Brienne of Tarth)
- Widow's Wail (Cersei Lannister, previously Joffrey Baratheon)
- Heartsbane (Samwell Tarly)

Oathkeeper and Widow's Wail were made from Ice, a Valyrian steel sword that previously belonged to House Stark. Ice was reforged into these two smaller swords, one given to Joffrey Baratheon (Widow's Wail) and the other given to Jaime Lannister who subsequently gave it to Brienne of Tarth.

There is also a dagger that was used to try and assassinate Bran Stark (S01E02).

Comment: How fitting for Cersei to end up with that sword, hadn't realized that until now

Comment: I'd emphasize that these are the four known to the *reader* (or viewer); there's no reason to think they are the only four in Westeros. They're rare, but probably not *that* rare.

Comment: @chepner - thanks for the suggestion, I've updated the answer

Comment: It seems like a lot of houses have one in their heirlooms, so probably a lot more around that just don't get mentioned (along with the fact that Littlefinger was able to win that dagger as a wager) until needed in the story.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet It is mentioned in the books that it is Valyrian-steel *swords* that are particularly priceless. Other things made of Valyrian steel are still rare and valuable, but lack the impossible-to-part-with heirloom quality that has become attached to the swords. So wagering a dagger comes far, far short of wagering one of the swords. (One of the houses has a Valyrian-steel axe that they treat the way others treat Valyrian-steel swords, but IIRC other houses with their own swords seem to think it a poor substitute.)

Comment: @KRyan - You realize my entire point was more that there were probably more out there than just four, right?  Regardless, my comment is a mess because (A) Littlefinger *lost* it, supposedly, (B) It's pretty clear he didn't actually lose it, and (C) it seems like even the daggers are considered incredibly valuable, as well. I don't dispute that they are considered priceless heirlooms, just that the idea that all of the listed in the books is an exhaustive list vs. ones that belong to characters in particular scenes.

Comment: @KRyan - see the answer by Mooz to the related question now linked/cited in this question.  Martin himself supports my theorizing about it, so we can consider that canon confirmation, I guess. Also, even more canon, is GEdgar's answer which cites a maester as logging 227 weapons/blades (not just swords).